# QGIS FS3 plugin user guide

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins, documentation

At 3.24.3 I have just installed the FS3 plugin for the first time.  Unfortunately, I have not found any documentation on how to use it. My searches have included the plugin's home page, as well as an internet search.

Failing any documentation, I tried to learn how it works by poking around in an organized manner, but the results have mostly generated Python errors.

FS3 has a 4-star rating on it's plugin page, so *somebody* has found out how to use it.  Alas, I'm still ignorant.

Where can I find user documentation for the FS3 plugin?

Comment: You can took an eye here, not really a tutorial, but it's a start : https://github.com/andreasfoulk/FS3/wiki and a PDF document to see how use it : https://cs-courses.mines.edu/csci370/FS2018/FinalReport/Newmont.pdf

Comment: It appears that your comment is the best available info, so if you want to convert it to an answer I'll award you the bounty.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First you have a wiki on [the plugin home page](https://github.com/andreasfoulk/FS3/wiki) but it isn't well documented and has a lot of TODO, but it can give some information. Look at the right, you'll have a table of contents.

Then, I found a Colorado School of Mines document with more information about the use :

- https://cs-courses.mines.edu/csci370/FS2018/FinalReport/Newmont.pdf

Hope these documents will help you.